# LLDB 'thread return' command emits error in a Swift function

Tags: swift, lldb

I am reading the [Dancing in the Debugger — A Waltz with LLDB](https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/) article. And I am trying the `thread return` command with Swift 2.2 as well as Swift 3.0.

My code is pretty simple:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let resust = test()
        print(resust)
    }

    func test() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

and I added a breakpoint at the beginning of the `test()` function with a `thread return false` action. However, after command+R, my program stops at the breakpoint as expect, but with the following error:

"error: Error returning from frame 0 of thread 1: We only support setting simple integer and float return types at present.."

Here's a screen shot:

[image: codesnapshot1]

Then I tried the same in Objective-C code; everything goes well.

Comment: Swift `Bool`s are implemented as a struct, so it isn't a "simple integer and float return type".  It works in ObjC because an ObjC `BOOL` is just a typedef of a primitive type.

Comment: I tried `thread return 10(or other number)` as the action, however the program still stopped with the same error. :(

Comment: Maybe it is implicitly converted to boolean value since Swift thread containers are type-safe?

Comment: @Leviathlon I have no idea.

Answer (score 9):

These are known bugs.  The value types in Swift (Int, Bool, etc.) are all complex objects, and we haven't taught lldb how to overwrite the return values for them.  Error handling will also make this tricky.

In general, forced returns are unsafe - more so with ARC and even more so with Swift, since you are likely to unbalance reference counts - not just on locals but potentially on objects passed in.

Comment: No.  We don't support structure returns in `thread return` in C yet either.  This is a somewhat specialized feature, and fairly tricky to implement, so it hasn't gotten to the top of anybody's queue yet.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Having this feature would allow to temporarily change some logic while debugging without recompiling the app, which would be very useful in some scenarios. I hope LLDB will learn to "thread return" more complex objects one day :)